# topic regarding POSIX thread

Tags: pthreads

> How does a thread knows when to exit?

SITUATION:

-while the main program must wait for the threads to run to completion.

-This can be done by using a prototype function called pthread_join.

-after all, a call to this function waits for the termination of the thread whose id is given by thread itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have called `pthread_join(ptherad_t &var)`the main will wait untill all the threads for which you have called join have exited.

once all the threads are completed their tasks,
when it  calls `pthread_exit(NULL)` main will exit.

inside the thread after its task is completed you need to call `pthread_exit(NULL)` which will stop the excution of the thread.But this is not mandatory and the thread can simply return which means that the thread has completed.

when it(thread)  calls `pthread_exit(NULL)`,the calling thread will exit.

Comment: i knew that; but if there is any complicated answers available.

Comment: That's not quite right. "After you have called pthread_join()the main will wait untill all the threads [exit]." - pthread_join requires a pthread_t argument identifying which thread to join - you usually call pthread_join for each thread you created in turn. Created threads need not call pthread_exit - simply returning from the function invoked by pthread_create works too, but pthread_exit can be used to specify a `void*` value to pass to pthread_join. There are other options - any thread can terminate the program with exit() - but they always don't clean up e.g. files & shared mem properly.

Comment: @Tony you are right but its just an overview of the OP's question.he just want to know when the main thread wants to exit.you are right in saying that created thread need not call ptherad_exit.